# Google Home on non-Google hardware

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I love the idea of [Google Home](https://madeby.google.com/home/). I want it. But I'm really cheap and don't want to fork out the $129 (and now $99 for a limited time only). What I do have is a Raspberry Pi.

What I would like to do is have access to the Google Home (note: **NOT** the Amazon Echo) libraries, or APIs that can be used on a Debian install. I may upgrade to a full PC running Ubuntu to do this as well, but would really like to get this working on a Pi3 running Raspbian. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! It is now possible and on a Raspberry Pi as well!

Here is the [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-DIY-Google-Assistant-With-Sleek-Wood-/) link on how to do it.

Used in this instructable:

Hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- Mini USB microphone
- Mini USB speaker
- Raspberry pi power adapter
- Raspberry pi micro SD card with **Raspian** OS installed
- 330ohm resistor
- 3mm warm white LED
- bread board prototyping wires
- electrical tape

Materials (enclosure):

- 10mm aluminum tube
- Tasmanian oak was used for the wood. Each board measured 24x9x1.2cm
- Wood finishing oil, I used Danish oil.
- 2mm wood screws
- 30mm wood screws

Tools:

- soldering iron
- tenon saw
- hand router
- bench chisel and mallet
- sand paper
- drill press
- electronics perfboard was used as a template for the speaker holes
- hacksaw
- flat file

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not?  According to this article from the Verge (as much as I hate the Verge):

> Google also promises to launch a Embedded Google Assistant SDK, which will allow tinkerers to load Google Assistant on a Raspberry Pi

http://www.theverge.com/2016/10/4/13164882/google-assistant-actions-on-google-developer-sdk

Official stuff: https://developers.google.com/actions/

Comment: Thanks @SiXandSeven8ths! That's pretty awesome. So I'll just have to wait for December then. If you see the official announcement and a link to the actual SDK, please link it in your answer!

Comment: From what I can tell, official Google SDK is coming in December, I added the Google link to my answer.  I can't seem to find anything else that would be an alternative, since the API and SDK haven't been released yet.

Comment: Ok, some more info - if anyone interested.  
- Actions is what is used to interract with the Goolge Assistant. and is available for tinkering right now https://developers.google.com/actions/
- Assistant SDK will only become available next year (2017) so that the assistant (home) can be installed on non-google hardware. Source: http://mashable.com/2016/10/04/google-assistant-sdk-2017/#CkSaU6OsEmqX

Comment: Good to know, @Jim.